# AutoMapper flattening

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to map source to destination with AutoMapper.
The types structure looks like this:

```
Source {
  public string SourceField1;
  public string SourceField2;
  public InnerSource Inner;
}

InnerSource {
  public string InnerSourceField3;
  public string InnerSourceField4;
}

Destination {
  public string DestinationField1;
  public string DestinationField2;
  public string DestinationField3;
  public string DestinationField4;
}
```

My solution was looking like:

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceField1))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceField2))
  .AfterMap((src, dest, context) => context.Mapper.Map(src.Inner, dest));

CreateMap<InnerSource, Destination>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InnerSourceField3))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField4, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InnerSourceField4))
```

And all this stuff seems to work, but not with EF and ProjectTo extension method, because AfterMap is not "compatible" with EF.

So my question is how to make this work with EF? Should I use some workarounds or is there another way to map this types structure without AfterMap?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Seems like IncludeMembers is what I need, but I don't have this method available. My AutoMapper version is 7.0.1 and I suggest this method added later

Comment: Upgrade or rename to use the default naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

```
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Inner)
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceField1))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceField2));
        CreateMap<InnerSource, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InnerSourceField3))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationField4, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InnerSourceField4));
```

Also you should to know that you can deny prefix